# How do I resolve Git Recv failure Error in VS Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, gitlab

I am trying to pull a branch after connecting to gitlab repository. However, I run into below error on running the git pull command:

fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.com/abc/xyz/': Recv failure: Connection was reset

Can you please help on solving this issue?

Comment: Can you view that URL in your browser?  Do you have two-factor authentication enabled?

Comment: This is a basic networking usage issue: for some reason your network can't stay connected to gitlab.com. This could be a transient network problem, and if not, it's likely a network configuration error at your end, suitable for superuser.com or serverfault.com.

Comment: @TimRoberts, I can access the gitlab url from browser and git remote add command works too, however on pull I get this error. I don't have two-factor authentication enabled

Comment: @torek: I have been facing this issue since last week, any way to check whats wrong with network configuration?

Comment: If it works from a browser, but not from Git, even though it's https either way, there is something odd in your network setup. For instance, perhaps you have some sort of SSL misconfiguration where your browser uses its own SSL but Git uses libcurl's ssl. Or, you might have a "no playing with the net" hardware box that limits your network access. You should name your OS and describe whether there is any middleware box that does something sneaky (e.g., cut off "unauthorized" traffic such as non-browser traffic).

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue on Github and this solution work for me:

```
VS Code setting --> Github --> Git protocol --> Change https to ssh
```

Comment: Great! Worked instantly